# Running Python unit tests without building extensions in-place

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-unittest

I have a Python 3.6 package that includes some Cython extensions. Let's assume its contents are the following:

```
# example/example.pyx

def add(int a, int b):
    return a + b
```

I can build this using `setuptools` with this script

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

example_ext = Extension(
    name='example.example',
    sources=['example/example.pyx'],
)

setup(
    name='Example package',
    packages=['example'],
    ext_modules=cythonize([example_ext]),
)
```

Now I can add a unit test:

```
# example/tests/test_example.py

import unittest
from example.example import add

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        result = add(4, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 9)
```

However, if I run `python -m unittest discover`, the tests fail with an `ImportError` since it cannot find the compiled Cython module. This happens even if I've already built the module using `python setup.py build_ext`.

The only way I've found to make the tests work is to build the Cython module in-place using `python setup.py build_ext -i`, but this seems like it should be unnecessary. Is there any way to tell the `unittest` library how to find the compiled Cython modules if I don't build in-place?

Comment: You can explicitly include the build directory to `sys.path`, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ python -m unittest discover`. However, building inplace seems to be the `distutils`/`setuptools` way since the extensions are also built inplace when running the tests via `python setup.py test`.

Comment: i had similar issue, and solved it with `--in-place`  as well. You can also move your test_example.py to the root folder. It should then find your module...